# Transparent CardView with Elevation issue

Tags: java, android, android-layout

When I want a Transparent CardView with some elevation the result will be as follows:

[image]

```xml
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#B3FFFFFF"

    app:cardElevation="8dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="#B3FFFFFF"
    app:cardCornerRadius="25dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/folder_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="@string/default_folder_name"
            android:importantForAutofill="no"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/folder_title"
            android:textColorHint="@color/folder_title_hint"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


        <!--this is only for the cardView to give it more space to display the issue-->
        <View
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

The `issue` is that there is a color difference inside the `CardView`, it should be like: [image]

When I replace `app:cardCornerRadius="25dp"` -> `app:cardCornerRadius="0dp"`, the size of the unwanted color difference increased.

Is this `issue` the way elevation works?
And are there workarounds?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: the color difference have to remove inside the `CardView`

Comment: If it's transparent, it *must* show what's behind. That's why it's called transparent.

Comment: @Prince Ali, edit the question

Comment: no, it's a `View` (sorry for indistinctness)

Comment: Yes that will make transparrent everything (means all child of that parent). Try to give value 0.7 or higher. i think that will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `CardView` it is not possible.

The workaround in this case is to remove `CardView` and set a `android:background="@drawable/shadowfile"`to the `LinearLayout`.

The file contains the `[transparency, elevation, radius]`.
**res/drawable/shadowfile.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- every item add a layer of evaluation to the border, with the padding you define how the evaluation is located around the border-->
    <item>
        <shape>
            <padding android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:bottom="1dp" android:left="1dp" />
            <solid android:color="#03000000" />
            <corners android:radius="20dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>    <item>
    <shape>
        <padding android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:bottom="1dp" android:left="1dp" />
        <solid android:color="#03000000" />
        <corners android:radius="20dp" />
    </shape>
    </item>    <item>
        <shape>
            <padding android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:bottom="1dp" android:left="1dp" />
            <solid android:color="#03000000" />
            <corners android:radius="20dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <padding android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:bottom="1dp" android:left="1dp" />
            <solid android:color="#03000000" />
            <corners android:radius="20dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <padding android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:bottom="1dp" android:left="1dp" />
            <solid android:color="#03000000" />
            <corners android:radius="20dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <padding android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:bottom="1dp" android:left="1dp" />
            <solid android:color="#03000000" />
            <corners android:radius="20dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <padding android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:bottom="1dp" android:left="1dp" />
            <solid android:color="#03000000" />
            <corners android:radius="20dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!-- Background -->
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#D2FFFFFF" />
            <corners android:radius="20dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this to your theme

```
<item name="elevationOverlayEnabled">false</item>
```